# Hiding a custom button from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

This is part of my code inside `UINavigationController` subclass. 
I've created a custom `UIButton` that will show most of the time.
How can I hide it in specific views?
I want to be able to `setHidden` the button inside some ViewControllers. The `UIButton` is a property.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _coolBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_coolBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 56, 39)];
    [_coolBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_coolBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomethingCool) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.navigationBar addSubview:_coolBtn];
}
```

Adding this inside the `ViewDidLoad` of the `ViewController` where I want to hide the button:

```
SubClassUInav *test =[[SubClassUInav alloc]init];
[test.coolBtn setHidden:YES];
```

Doesn't work.

**Edit:**
Maybe it's because I'm creating a new instance of it?
I'm not referencing to this subclass in my code. The only thing I did was to add it as a custom class inside the IB when the `UINavigationController` is selected.

Comment: If this is your custom navigation controller class, then assign property to your coolBtn. And then you can access this property outside the class where you can call, [myNavigationController.coolBtn setHidden:Yes]; // myNavigationController reference required.

Comment: That's doesn't work. I've edited my question.

Comment: But you are alloc initing a new instance and hiding the button of that instance whereas you should ask the already existing instance to hide the button.

Comment: I've edited my question again. The problem is that I don't have an existing instance (that I'm aware of) of the subclass. I'm not referencing to this subclass in my code. The only thing I did was to add it as a custom class inside the IB when the UINavigationController is selected. of course I can access it by doing something like `self.navigationController` but I don't know how I can access its properties.

Comment: @Sha: Check my added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you have to do.

In **SubClassUINav.h**:

```
@interface SubClassUInav : UINaviagationController {}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *coolBtn;
```

In **SubClassUINav.m**:

```
@synthesize _coolBtn = coolBtn;
```

In your **MyViewController.m**:

```
#import "SubClassUINav.h"    

// get reference of your nav controller, do not create new instance by alloc-init
    SubClassUINav *subClassUINavInstance = (SubClassUINav *) self.navigationController
    [subClassUINavInstance.coolBtn setHidden: YES]; //Access your properties
```

Hope now you get a clear view.

Comment: Works! one small question if you don't mind. Inside my subclass i added `_coolBtn.tag = 5;` and inside the viewController `UIButton *random = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:5];
    random.alpha = 0;` but that also didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: There might be some other view with the same tag number. That's why its better to go with Property than to tag.. Because code also become readable, like which button actually you are referring is clearer just by looking into your code. Whereas tag number will not specify that.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it with using NotificationCenter like bellow

**Add observer in NSNotificationCenter from button Define class:-**

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(HideButton:)
                                                 name:@"HideButton"
                                               object:nil];

-(void)HideButton:(NSNotification *)notification {

    hide button code

}
```

**Calling this using Bellow code:-**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HideButton" object:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is this line

```
SubClassUInav *test =[[SubClassUInav alloc]init];
```

This creates a new instance and in that instance the button state will be hidden.In your class somewhere you will be doing the same which is added as subview.Use that instance and make it hidden